# Intermittent disabling of hardware (Wi-Fi, Mic, possibly cell antenna) on iPhone 7 Plus

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, microphone

**DISCLAIMER/NOTE**

First, I've been a long time iPhone user and I like to keep up on it's updates and I'm very familiar with this device.  Likewise, my iPhone 7 Plus is my 3rd iPhone.  I'm only mentioning this to be clear, I'm familiar with these devices and I've legitimately tried everything I can think of to troubleshoot these issues.  What I'd like to know is what I can do to fix this and not be without a phone for a few days, possibly waiting for a shipped replacement.

**DETAILS**

For the past couple of weeks, I've been experiencing some unusual and extremely annoying issues with my iPhone.  It first started just before the new year (probably 10-12 days ago) when I received a call from my wife and, out of habit, I went to press the speaker button and nothing happened. I started to pay attention, and I noticed that the speaker button was disabled.  I held the phone to my ear and said "Hello", multiple times, and received no response.  I hung up.  My wife called me back and I had the same experience again. I restarted the phone (turned it off, waited a 60-90 seconds, cut it back on) and gave her a call.  She picked up, but still the speaker icon was disabled and and she couldn't hear me.

I went over to text her, I tapped the mic button so I could try to dictate a text and the button flickered like it was tapped, but it never transitioned into the "listening" state.

This was annoying but I also knew I had held off on wanting to install the most recent, iOS 13.3 update.  I then went and installed it.  When it came back, I texted my wife to call me.  She did and it worked! Great!

However, yesterday I received another phone call.  Once again, I had the same issue as before.  My microphone on my phone isn't working and for all places that I can go to test the mic on my phone, it has disabled buttons or when I tap them, it's like they can't initialize the mic.  The truly weird thing has been that since yesterday, sometimes, I can restart my phone, try again and it works, but the restart doesn't always work and it's usually temporary and works for no more than an hour.

Another issue that has arisen since I installed iOS 13.3 is that my Wi-Fi device is also disabled.  The Wi-Fi button from the slide-up menu is disabled, and when  I go into settings on my iPhone, the Disable/Enable button for Wi-Fi is also, completely disabled.

I've also experienced other hardware quirks.  There have been times where I've had no cell signal, and normally I would. Yesterday, and this only happened once, I had my headphones plugged into the device and the phone wouldn't register that it was plugged in.  Audio was always play through the device speakers.  A restart fixed it until I unplugged the headphones and plugged them back in.  Again, it stopped working and a restart didn't fix it after that.

Doing some research online, some of these issues were once an issue with iPhone 7 & 7 Pluses back in 2017 and Apple was replacing phones, even if they were out of warranty or not under Apple care.  I've subsequently found that since iOS 13.3 has come out, others are reporting issues with their 7/7 Plus's with the mic not working.  The cause is, supposedly, a software issue and not one with the hardware.

I'm not looking to replace my phone, unless I have too.  I'd be glad to take it to an Apple service center and get them to give me a refurbed unit, but I've heard that some users still have the same issue with the refurb models, plus I live over an hour away from the nearest Apple store. I don't want to have to deal with that, and simply get another phone that on the next day might behave the same way.

Other than replacing this device, has anyone experienced this issue and found a good solution, or at a minimum, found a consistent set of steps they can walk through that will fix these issues, guaranteed? Alternatively, has anyone else experience weird, internal hardware issues similar to this and, in fact, the hardware was faulty?

I keep a limited data plan (which is intentional), so Wi-Fi is important plus, what good is a cell phone if you can't talk on it?

**STEPS I'VE TAKEN TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE**

This is Stack Exchange, so I know the follow-up response will be "what have you tried?"  Here's a list of all that I can think of that I've tried to fix this issue, in no specific order.

1. Restarted the device with generous pauses between turning it back on. This works intermittently, but never for long. I know devices don't work this way, but it's as if it "decides" to stop working for a while, and nothing fixes it.  If I try a restart on the next day, or 5 hours later, it might work.  3-4 consecutive restarts, however, might not do the trick.
2. I was formerly on iOS version 13.1.  I upgraded to the latest version, 13.3, and no updates are pending.
3. I've put the phone in Airplane mode, waited a couple of minutes and cut it back on. This has never worked.
4. I've completely disabled Bluetooth.  After forgetting all formerly paired devices and disabling Bluetooth completely, I restarted my phone. Again, this doesn't seem to affect the problem.
5. I've tested the mic with Notes, text messaging, Siri and of course making phone calls.  Once it's broken, it's broken across all apps on the entire device, so this isn't an app-specific issue. It seems to be an operating system/hardware issue.